# NumberPicker Display more than 3 values. Modify Android Internal Class

Tags: java, android

I have a number picker that displays 3 values at a time. Although there is plenty of space between these values. Is there any way to change that?

Inside Android's internal number picker class there is this variable:

```java
public class NumberPicker extends LinearLayout {

    /**
     * The number of items show in the selector wheel.
     */
    private static final int SELECTOR_WHEEL_ITEM_COUNT = 3;
```

How can someone modify that?

[image]

Comment: can you explain what you wanna do exactly , you want to have more than 3 number pickers , is that it ?

Comment: Each NumberPicker displays only 3 values a a time. Although there is plenty of space between each value. I want to display 10 for example

Comment: looking through the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html , i don't think that is possible as it's not mentioned there .

Comment: Wrong. A number picker only lets you pick one number, not 3. You can place as many number pickers as you want. Since you control the layout, you control the spacing between number pickers.

Comment: You obviously didnt understand the question. I want EACH number picker to display more than THREE VALUES

Comment: And you didn't understand my answer. Each number picker only displays ONE value.

Comment: one? i see three values per number picker. For example the left one displays 119, 120, 121. I want it to display more than three since there is space between these values

Comment: You must not be using a NumberPicker. You're probably using something else like a TimePicker or DatePicker (which are built from 3 NumberPickers). But a NumberPicker only lets you select one number.

Comment: I suggest you lookup how to use a NumberPicker.

Comment: Oh god you still havent understand the question

Comment: I DONT want to SELECT i want to DISPLAY MORE values per NumberPicker. For example: The left number picker has range from 0 - 150. There is a lot of space between 119, 120, 121. So why not DISPLAY more values? For example TEN values? I DONT want to select

Comment: So you mean you want to display more selection values for an individual number picker. You can't. That's not how the number picker widget works.

Comment: @John: Make the SELECTOR_WHEEL_ITEM_COUNT = 5; or something else and change the height of NumberPicker = "300dp" (Depending upon ITEM_COUNT) It is working as expected. I tried just now.

Comment: SELECTOR_WHEEL_ITEM_COUNT is unchangable and height of NumberPicker to 300dp doesn't work either...

Comment: @Mia you have to take older version of NumberPicker. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77273614/5694410